# Type conversion complex variables in C++

Tags: c++, casting, type-conversion, complex-numbers, function-call

```
std::complex<double> a;
int t=2;
a = 100; //This line upon printing, gives me (100,0)
a*t;
```

The last line in the above code is wrong because the complex class doesn't allow for multiplication between a complex variable and a non-complex variable. Therefore, I tried to do:

```
std::complex<double> z = a*std::complex<double>(t)
```

This threw up an error:
error: no matching function for call to `std::complex<double>::complex`

Is there a better way to deal with this type conversion?

Comment: What do you think is wrong here? You can perfectly well multiply a real number by a complex number. A real number **is** a complex number (just with `0` imaginary part).

Comment: `t` is not initialized, and where is the definition of `z`? That last line works fine for me if `z` is an `std::complex<double>`

Comment: "The last line in the above code is clearly wrong." maybe clear to you but not to anybody else, please explain. I dont think you need to convert anything here

Comment: Please, prove minimal, working example. And also rephrase your question, so we better know, what exactly is an issue.

Comment: I have made changes to the code to. The complex class template doesn't allow multiplication between a complex variable and a non-complex variable. That is why directly multiplying a and t is wrong

Comment: The multiplication conflict is not between complex and non-complex but between `complex<double>` and `int`. Multiplying by a `double` will work.

Comment: What standard are you using and what version of g++/clang++?  because it worked for me in clang++, https://repl.it/repls/UnimportantLuminousSymbol

Comment: @SiddharthBachoti: You made changes to `std::complex<T>` ??! That is Undefined Behavior, right there, and any outcome is correct.

Comment: Is the whole error? It doesn't look like a complete error message.

Comment: *"Is there a better way to deal with this type conversion?"* Maybe [this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/zFw0hJB90PKd6uAv).